# TypeScript - Visual Studio - d3

Tags: d3.js, typescript

I created a new TypeScirpt project, added the json file to the solution, changed the 'Copy to Output directory' property to Copy always.

When I F5 the project, the browser complains that it cannot find the resource *somedata.json*

If I run the python SimpleHTTPServer, load up the same html file, it works.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     d3.json("somedata.json", draw);
 </script>
```

Thank you.

Comment: You verified that `somedata.json` ended up in the root of the output directory where you expected it to be?  If you drag the file from the solution explorer onto your text file, what path does it add?

Comment: Yes, those all look good. the json file is where it should be. If I run the python http server there, it all works. I'm running Windows 8 with IISExpress

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the full path from the root of the site to obtain the `somedata.json` file?

```
d3.json("/scripts/somedata.json", draw);
```

Replace `/scripts/` with the correct path in your instance, but start the address with a leading `/` to make it relative to the root.

Comment: In Visual Studio I created a folder *data*. 

d3.json("/data/somedata.json", draw);

It didn't work from studio but it did work from python.

Weird, I'm missing something simple.

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to MIME types that the server used by Visual Studio is allowed to serve. You can define such MIME types at web.config btw if this is an ASP.net project.

Also see this official example in case it helps:
http://www.typescriptlang.org/Samples#D3

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to run the project using ASP.NET Development Server?